# How to overcome the limit of records returned in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I sent the following request using postman:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns
```

And the response was of 1000 records. Is there a way to overcome the limit of records? I tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$top=5000
```

I retrieve the same result. Only 1000 records. Is there a way to overcome that limit?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `$top` query parameter is not intended to be an alternative to data paging. It is intended to control the *size* of each page, and it has an upper limit of `999` records per page. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter):

> $top accepts a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 999 (inclusive).

The default page size for most endpoints is `100` records. For most use cases, this default should be left at the default. There are exceptions, but most of the time it is to *reduce* the page size (i.e. optimized for low memory or mobile devices).

Instead of setting massive page sizes, you should iterate through the paged data returned by Graph. This process is outlined in [Paging Microsoft Graph data in your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging). For example, using C# you might do something along these lines:

```cs
// Create a bucket to hold the final results
var userList = new List<User>(); 

// Request the first page of data
var usersPage = await graphServiceClient
    .Users
    .GetAsync();

// Add the first page of data to the final list
userList.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);

// Repeate until all pages have been returned
while (usersPage.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    usersPage = await usersPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    userList.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marc. I understood everything you wrote about `$ top`. I have a couple of doubts, can I retrieve unlimited records from Microsoft Graph related to singIns requesting all pages? For example, if I have 15 million records, can I retrieve all data by calling nextlink until there is no data? The company gave me a requirement: get all logs of user logins. Is it possible?.

Comment: That is exactly how it works, you follow each nextLink until you reach the final page (which won't have a nextLink).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You can also use the PageIterator<T> class to iterate through result pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp

Comment: I ran into the problem that I had a `.Top(25)` in the `graphServiceClient` statement, which will result in an endless loop because it will continue to return the same first 25 records and `usersPage.NextPageRequest` will never be `null`.  So be carefull by evaluating the condition `usersPage.NextPageRequest != null` if you use any query options like `top`

Answer (score 2):

[$top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter) accepts a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 999 (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

A thank you to Marc whose answer pointed me in the right direction for processing a list of files from a SharePoint document library:

```
    private static async Task<List<string>> GetDriveItems(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string driveId)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            AuthenticationConfig config = AuthenticationConfig.ReadFromJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            var driveitems = await graphClient
                .Sites[$"{config.SiteID}"]
                .Lists[$"{driveId}"]
                .Drive
                .List
                .Items.Request().Expand(i => i.DriveItem).GetAsync();
            foreach (var driveItem in driveitems)
            {
                items.Add(driveItem.DriveItem.Name);
            }
            while (driveitems.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                driveitems = await driveitems.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                foreach (var driveItem in driveitems)
                {
                    items.Add(driveItem.DriveItem.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine($"GetDriveItems: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ResetColor();
            throw;
        }
        return items;
    }
```